# How to access the firestore database in the google app engine

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to access my firestore database inside mine google app engine to read and write data.

Is it possibe to read the data there?

I tried to read the data using the `firebase admin sdk` , but it giving me error .

***app.js***

```
'use strict';


const express = require('express');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const app = express();

app.get('/', (res) => {
  console.log(admin.firestore().collection("hello").doc("fdfadsdfas").set({
      name:"kushal "
  }))
  res.status(200).send('Hello i am learning google app engine, world!').end();
});


// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: can you share the error that you are receiving?

Is your database in Firebase or in GCP?

Comment: Per @JorgeHDZ it would be helpful to include your error. There is only one Google Firestore service. You are able to access this from Firebase, App Engine and anywhere else through its endpoint. I've not tried this myself (!) but you may need to use the Google Cloud Firestore library (`@google-cloud/firestore`) from App Engine rather than `firebase-admin`. The data model will be otherwise unchanged. See: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers